# Member 'xxx' implicitly has an 'any' type which is mutation in Vuex-class

Tags: typescript, vuejs2, vuex

I am trying to implement a store in Vue with typescript y using [Vuex-class](https://github.com/ktsn/vuex-class).To do that written following code and while building following error occurred.Since it is a mutation,it should not expect initialization. Correct me if i am wrong and in my code.

```
ERROR in C:/workspace/vue/packages/gui/src/client/services/GetSessionIdService.vue
13:46 Member 'setSessionId' implicitly has an 'any' type.
    11 | })
    12 | export default class GetSessionIdService extends Vue{
  > 13 |     @Mutation(sessionMutations.setSessionId) setSessionId;
       |                                              ^
    14 |     @State(state => state.session.sessionId) sessionId;
    15 |     public $store:any;
    16 |     public async getSessionIdFromService(){
```

Code:

```
import {Mutation, State} from 'vuex-class';
import {Component, Vue} from 'vue-property-decorator';
import {sessionModule, sessionMutations} from '../store/session-module';
export default class GetSessionIdService extends Vue{    
    @Mutation(sessionMutations.setSessionId) setSessionId;
    @State(state => state.session.sessionId) sessionId;
}
```

Mutations:

```
import {Module, Mutation, VuexModule} from 'vuex-module-decorators';
const namespace = 'session';
const mutationNames = ['setSessionId'];
const sessionMutations = mutationNames.reduce((mutations: any, methodName: string) => {
  const mutationName = `${namespace}/${methodName}`;
  mutations[methodName] = mutationName;
  return mutations;
}, {});

@Module({namespaced: true, name: namespace})
class sessionModule extends VuexModule {
  public sessionId:string='';

  @Mutation setSessionId(sessionId: any) {
    this.sessionId = sessionId;
  } 

}

export {sessionModule, sessionMutations};
```